# Java equivalent of visual basic tab function

Tags: java, string, vb6, formatting, string-formatting

I am attempting to convert some old VB6 code into java for my company. I have all of it done except for the formatting of the strings. In the old VB6 code they would use the Tab(N) function to dictate where the string would be positioned on a line as it was being written to a text file. I have been looking for some way to duplicate this in any way with Java. I am attempting right now to figure out the String.format method, but I'm slightly confused on how it functions. Is there any other function or any way I can set the absolute position of a string on a line in java? One example is the first string is 15 characters long and the next string in the line needs to be at line position 50, while another string is 4 characters long and each string after that is supposed to be at position 19, 34, 41, 51, 59, 66, 76, 83, and 90. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example:

```
(name)                                           PRODUCTION DATE    : (date)

SERVICE           PROC  MODS       BILLED       ALLOWED      PAID          ADJ    ADJ    LINE REMARK
DATE              CODE           UNI    AMT       AMT     UNI    AMT       AMT    CODES  CODE
```

Comment: String.format or one of the many printf methods is the best tool for the job.  There are many many printf tutorial pages;  I suggest searching for them.

Comment: Thanks, I have never used any of the printf methods before. I will check them out

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and ended up creating a builder for this.

```
public class TabLineBuilder {

    int length;
    private String line;
    StringBuilder sb;

    public TabLineBuilder(int length) {
        this.length = length;
        initialize(); // call non-overridable method
    }

    public TabLineBuilder insert(int pos, String text) {
        sb.replace(pos, pos + text.length(), text);
        line = sb.toString();
        return this;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return line;
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // new line of spaces
        line = String.format("%" + length + "s", ' ');
        sb = new StringBuilder(line);
    }

    public void clear() {
        // Overridable public method
        initialize();
    }
}
```

Example:

```
TabLineBuilder tlb = new TabLineBuilder(120);
String line = tlb.insert(0, "(name)").insert(50, "PRODUCTION DATE").toString();
System.out.println(line);
tlb.clear();
line = tlb.insert(0, "DATE").insert(19, "CODE").insert(34, "UNI").toString();
System.out.println(line);
tlb.clear();
```

Output:

```
(name)                                            PRODUCTION DATE                                                       
DATE               CODE           UNI
```